# Payment API for Android application

Tags: android

I would like to integrate payment API for my android app but am still confused with different ways available. I checked PayPal API, Google checkout. In Google checkout there are several options like Email invoices, Buy Now buttons,etc. Actually my requirement is like, I need to purchase a voucher card from an Organization. So can you suggest me a suitable mechanism to achieve this requirement? Also that mechanism should accept all cards.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you still haven't got the solution for your query, better unaccept the accepted answer so that other can know that you still haven't got the right solution yet.

Comment: Done... Actually first time I couldn't do that integration and that link works fine for me and I accepted that answer... Then only I realize that the requirement is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MECL](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index) is the Library which will do your Job, User can make payment without having Paypal account i.e. via Cards.

Comment: @Pratheeja if you use paypal mpl then you can not pay with card.

Comment: ok. Thanks. But with paypal I can use all kind of accounts like visa, master card etc.. right?

Comment: @Pratheeja yes.But read paypal document for supported country.

Comment: @Pratheeja if you use paypal mpl you cannot pay with any card.

Comment: Actually my requiremnt is like I need a provision to enter my card number and details. Can I do it with paypal MECL library? Or Can you suggest me a suitable option..

Comment: in MECL if you see example then you have option like Mastercard or Descovery or many more option available.